# domDocument - Identifying position of a <br />

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm using domDocument to parse some HTML, and want to replace breaks with \n. However, I'm having problems identifying where a break actually occurs within the document.

Given the following snippet of HTML - from a much larger file that I'm reading using $dom->loadHTMLFile($pFilename):

```
<p>Multiple-line paragraph<br />that has a close tag</p>
```

and my code:

```
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('*') as $domElement) {
    switch (strtolower($domElement->nodeName)) {
        case 'p' :
            $str = (string) $domElement->nodeValue;
            echo 'PARAGRAPH: ',$str,PHP_EOL;
            break;
        case 'br' :
            echo 'BREAK: ',PHP_EOL;
            break;
    }
}
```

I get:

```
PARAGRAPH: Multiple-line paragraphthat has a close tag
BREAK:
```

How can I identify the position of that break within the paragraph, and replace it with a \n ?

Or is there a better alternative than using domDocument for parsing HTML that may or may not be well-formed?

Comment: Well, you could always use regex. Or simpler than DD would be `print htmlqp($html)->find("br")->replaceWith("\n")->top("body")->html();`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't get the position of an element using `getElementsByTagName`. You should go through `childNodes` of each element and process text nodes and elements separately.

In the general case you'll need recursion, like this:

```
function processElement(DOMNode $element){
    foreach($element->childNodes as $child){
        if($child instanceOf DOMText){
            echo $child->nodeValue,PHP_EOL;
        }elseif($child instanceOf DOMElement){
            switch($child->nodeName){
            case 'br':
                echo 'BREAK: ',PHP_EOL;
                break;
            case 'p':
                echo 'PARAGRAPH: ',PHP_EOL;
                processElement($child);
                echo 'END OF PARAGRAPH;',PHP_EOL;
                break;
            // etc.
            // other cases:
            default:
                processElement($child);
            }
        }
    }
}

$D = new DOMDocument;
$D->loadHTML('<p>Multiple-line paragraph<br />that has a close tag</p>');
processElement($D);
```

This will output:

```
PARAGRAPH: 
Multiple-line paragraph
BREAK:
that has a close tag
END OF PARAGRAPH;
```

Comment: Hmmmm.... seems like an idea with strong possibilities. I'll give it a go with some real world examples and see how it works out. Thanks.

Comment: Nice, quick and clean, and allows me to process all the other "self-contained" tags such as <hr /> as well. I can even process nested tables efficiently. My test code looks like spaghetti at the moment, but that's my problem (I'm still in the experimental stage with the logic at the moment, I'll refactor it later when I'm satisfied it all works), the method is great

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't have to deal with child-nodes and other stuff, why not just replace the br?

```
$str = '<p>Multiple-line paragraph<br />that has<br>a close tag</p>';
echo preg_replace('/<br\s*\/?>/', "\n", $str);
```

output:

```
<p>Multiple-line paragraph
that has
a close tag</p>
```

Alternative (using Dom):

```
$str = '<p>Multiple-line<BR>paragraph<br />that<BR/>has<br>a close<Br>tag</p>';

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($str);

// using xpath here, because it will find every br-tag regardless
// of it being self-closing or not
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//br') as $br) {
  $br->parentNode->replaceChild($dom->createTextNode("\n"), $br);
}

// output whole html
echo $dom->saveHtml();

// or just the body child-nodes
$output = '';
foreach ($xpath->query('//body/*') as $bodyChild) {
  $output .= $dom->saveXml($bodyChild);
}

echo $output;
```

Comment: Potentially, though I could be dealing with much larger user-generated HTML files containing all manner of markup, and I think I'd prefer to use $dom->loadHTMLFile($pFilename) rather than a manual load, str_replace, and then $dom->loadHTML($htmlString)... particularly for the memory overheads

Comment: @MarkBaker Will you be doing other things on the markup besides the `br`-search?

Comment: A whole lot more, most of which I could handle with my basic loop and switch test, but primarily extracting tables to generate as 2-D arrays, likewise text with styles (inline and css)... the core purpose is to create a decent Reader for HTML files that can be used to populate a PHPExcel worksheet object in much the same way that MS Excel can load an HTML file.... the killer to my method was tags such as <br /> and <hr /> that are "self-contained"

Comment: @MarkBaker *...the killer to my method was tags...* then have a look at the xpath example above ;)

Comment: Using XPath is something that I hadn't considered before, will do some experimenting... the replaceChild will also deal with potential attribute issues like <hr align="left" noshade> as well

Comment: A good alternative approach to the problem. I ran some tests last night and it works cleanly and does exactly what I needed, but nearly 3x slower and more memory overhead than Hrant's answer. Trying to figure out if I can split bounties.

Comment: @MarkBaker I think you don't need to, if Hrants answer works better for you then it's the answer that should be accepted.

Comment: you deserve some reward both for the effort you put into helping me, and the lateral thinking to use xPath for search/replace before walking the dom... I've upvoted, but that's all I can see to do

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple class that doesn't use recursion and should be faster/consume less memory, but basically same primitive idea as @Hrant Khachatrian's (iterate through all elements and look for child tags's):

```
class DomScParser {

    public static function find(DOMNode &$parent_node, $tag_name) {
        //Check if we already got self-contained node
        if (!$parent_node->childNodes->length) {
            if ($parent_node->nodeName == $tag_name) {
                return $parent_node;
            }
        }
        //Initialize path array
        $dom_path = array($parent_node->firstChild);
        //Initialize found nodes array
        $found_dom_arr = array();
        //Iterate while we have elements in path
        while ($dom_path_size = count($dom_path)) {
            //Get last elemant in path
            $current_node = end($dom_path);
            //If it is an empty element - nothing to do here,
            //we should step back in our path.
            if (!$current_node) {
                array_pop($dom_path);
                continue;
            }

            if ($current_node->firstChild) {
                //If node has children - add it first child to end of path.
                //As we are looking for self-contained nodes without children,
                //this node is not what we are looking for - change corresponding
                //path elament to his sibling.
                $dom_path[] = $current_node->firstChild;
                $dom_path[$dom_path_size - 1] = $current_node->nextSibling;
            } else {
                //Check if we found correct node, if not - change corresponding
                //path elament to his sibling.
                if ($current_node->nodeName == $tag_name) {
                    $found_dom_arr[] = $current_node;
                }
                $dom_path[$dom_path_size - 1] = $current_node->nextSibling;
            }
        }
        return $found_dom_arr;
    }

    public static function replace(DOMNode &$parent_node, $search_tag_name, $replace_tag) {
        //Check if we got Node to replace found node or just some text.
        if (!$replace_tag instanceof DOMNode) {
            //Get DomDocument object
            if ($parent_node instanceof DOMDocument) {
                $dom = $parent_node;
            } else {
                $dom = $parent_node->ownerDocument;
            }
            $replace_tag=$dom->createTextNode($replace_tag);
        }
        $found_tags = self::find($parent_node, $search_tag_name);
        foreach ($found_tags AS &$found_tag) {
            $found_tag->parentNode->replaceChild($replace_tag->cloneNode(),$found_tag);
        }
    }

}

$D = new DOMDocument;
$D->loadHTML('<span>test1<br />test2</span>');
DomScParser::replace($D, 'br', "\n");
```

P.S. Also it shoudn't break on multiple nested tags as it doesn't use recursion. Example html:

```
$html=str_repeat('<b>',100).'<br />'.str_repeat('</b>',100);
```

Comment: Thanks for this.... I'll do some speed/memory tests and see how efficient it is in comparison with the other solutions... Hrant's recursive works very well, but if I can avoid recursion it should be faster, especially as it would mean I can use local variables for speed until it's completed parsing before I move the data to class variables

Comment: @Mark Baker, No problem, but I think you should just use this class instead of using local variables - you will not notice speed difference. One function call is not noticable and if you pass everything by reference(and in most cases even if you don't) PHP will not create any new variables, it uses "copy on write" logic (explanation example: http://hengrui-li.blogspot.com/2011/08/php-copy-on-write-how-php-manages.html). Btw, it would be great if you created some speed/memory tests for all this methods and added them to your main post.

Comment: Sadly, when 99% of feedback for the library in question is complaints about its speed and memory usage, I can't consider any optimisation as premature :( and with the size of the HTML fragments in question, speed is noticeable